# raco pkg: install subfolder of git repo

Tags: git, package, racket

How can I install a subfolder of a Git repo as a Racket package?

e.g., if repo `foo` has 2 folders `pkg` and `etc`, how do I tell `raco pkg install` to ignore `etc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `?path=pkg` at the end of the URL:

```
   https://github.com/USER/foo.git?path=pkg
```

(Docs: see the 5th bullet under [Package Sources](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/Package_Concepts.html#%28part._concept~3asource%29) or the 2nd paragraph under [Git deployment](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/getting-started.html#%28part._github-deploy%29))

If the Git repo contains multiple folders that should be part of the package (maybe `pkg1` and `pkg2`), put an `info.rkt` like this in the repo:

```
#lang info
(define collection 'multi)
(define setup-collects '("pkg1" "pkg2"))
(define compile-omit-paths '("other"))
```

Then `raco pkg install https://github.com/USER/foo.git` will ignore the `other` folder.